# docker tool box でlaradockのインストールについて

Tags: docker

LaradockをWindows 10 Homeにインストールをしようとしています。

下記のURLを参考に進めていまして、[Laradockをインストール（クローン）する] まで進めています。

参考にしているURL:
[LaradockをWindows 10 Homeにインストール](https://pg-happy.jp/laradoc-windows10-home-install.html)

`docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace` を行った後に`http://192.168.99.100` にアクセスすると

```
このサイトにアクセスできません
192.168.99.100 で接続が拒否されました。
```

という状態になっており、なぜ接続が拒否されているかが分かりません。

`docker ps` で確認したところnginxは起動しています。
以下はdocer psの実行結果です。

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
a0d0a8469f73        laradock_nginx        "nginx"                  8 hours ago         Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   laradock_nginx_1
d267e44d2283        laradock_php-fpm      "php-fpm"                8 hours ago         Up 4 seconds        9000/tcp                                   laradock_php-fpm_1
67af0d973a92        laradock_phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 hours ago         Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:88->80/tcp                         laradock_phpmyadmin_1
6694dd854f6e        laradock_workspace    "/sbin/my_init"          8 hours ago         Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp                       laradock_workspace_1
90f08bc93dd8        laradock_redis        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                     laradock_redis_1
c4d6bf532383        laradock_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 hours ago         Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp          laradock_mysql_1
```

初歩的な質問かもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `docker ps` の実行結果を質問文に含めておくと、回答のヒントになるかもしれません。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。docker psの実行結果を追記しました。